# Windows 8 - Driver conflict issue

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, usb, drivers, mouse

Recently, all USB devices stopped working on my laptop.  Devices are powered but not working.  Mice, drives, keyboards, and all other devices.  For example, when I plug a mouse in, it is identified correctly in device manager, but with a yellow exclamation mark by it.  Also, several identical devices appear in 
DM, but they are hidden.  Same with my Passport backup drive.  When I boot up in safe mode however, I can use my mouse/keyboard.  I'm in desperate need of a fix here before I revert back to Win7!  Any ideas?

Comment: What's the actual error (code) shown for the device(s) in the device manager?  Have you tried a System Restore/Refresh to back to when it was working?

Comment: I don't remember what the error code was, how do you find it?  Also I don't have any system restore points from when it was working.

Comment: Look at the devices properties via the device manager (right-click -. properties).  When you find that info, please Edit and update your question with it (and any other pertinent information you may discover).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

- System restore.
- While booting up press F8 or something ( the same menu allows you to choose SAFE MODE ) and   choose 'Last known configuration'

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll try that as soon as I get back home.  How does it know what the last known working state is?

Comment: It stores that state somewhere but this solution works in may problems.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was a driver for a "Virtual USB device".  Basically this driver was higher priority than all other USB devices, so it was causing conflicts even with basic devices like mice and keyboards.  I used [DriverView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/driverview.html) to diagnose the problem and delete the offending driver.